# Network Signal strength in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have tried many possible ways of detecting signal strength in React and showing them in signal bars like Weak, Medium, Excellent. The solution I built was in plain javascript where we download a image from server and calculate download time but that needs interval to run again and again and is pushing load on server. Is there any way to do the same in React way ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to add `change eventListener` to **experimental**
[NetworkInformation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) and calculate your signal based on `downlink` attribute

But its not well supported yet

Comment: Its not supported in all browsers..So currently no luck